# How to Update Assets Folder in Android Dynamically from Web Service?

Tags: android, json, web-services, jackson, assets

In `assets` folder in my Android project, i have `.dat` and `.xml` files. They must be updated periodically. I don't want to update them by myself, there is a web service that i will store new `.dat` and `.xml` files as `.json` objects. How may i make the application update `assets` folder by itself?

Thanks.

Comment: The `assets` folder, once created after installing an app becomes a _read-only_ folder. Your best bet, I reckon, is to create a folder in the device memory and use that from your app's code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Siddharth Lele mentions in the comments, you cannot update `assets/` at runtime, except by upgrading the app to one that contains a newer `assets/`.

You can, however, download your `.dat` and `.xml` files to internal storage. Then, when you need to use one of these files, check internal storage first. If there is a file there, use it. If not, fall back to the copy in `assets/`.